# Would like to bypass CDN domain via HTACCESS. Need assistance for rewriting rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, litespeed

I have been searching the internet for some hours and tried different solutions, but i gave up. Now trying specific here.

I am running a server for a WordPress site (Litespeed enterprise, CentOS 7)
I am trying to achieve a rewrite rule in htaccess for bypassing the CDN for local visitors. 
e.x all static files in WP goes trough cdn.example.com (CNAME for another record at CDN provider)
Now i want 1 specific country to NOT retrieve files from "https://cdn.example.com" (static files) but instead directly via origin https://example.com

I am using geoIP module for detecting users from a specific country - which works great (tested)
But how can I rewrite inside WP the URLs to go trough https://example.com instead?
The CDN mapping is done inside WP via Litespeed cache plugin, and it has changed all the URLs to CDN.example.com which is perfect for all non-local users, but i would like to make an exception for local users in our country, since CDN has no POP and it doesnt make a sense to route traffic to another country.

I tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(BE)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://cdn.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is that even correct and a valid approach?

Looking forward to hear from you :) Thanks so much

Comment: The DNS entry for `cdn.example.com` presumably doesn’t point to your server to begin with here, but the CDN provider’s server? Then you can not rewrite these requests using _your_ server, because they are not _going to_ your server.

Comment: You are damn right. How could i oversee it!!! 
Is there a way to accomplish my goal? To "rewrite" the URL according to visitors. I can check on the GEOIP COUNTRY CODE to determine whom i will want to "rewrite"

Or is this a new plugin development?

Comment: Well you _could_ refer to the images using a URL below your own domain first - and then redirect those requests _to_ the CDN URL, for any “foreign” visitors … But that is probably not the best idea in terms of performance, you’d be adding an extra redirect, kinda perverts the usage of a CDN for performance reasons to begin with. The other alternative would be that you do your detection in PHP, and then based on that output different image URLs, either the local or the CDN version.